# Spring Web Services - Exception Skipping ExceptionResolver

Tags: java, web-services, soap, spring-ws

I have a SOAP service, the request and responses work as expected with good input, if I specify bad input for an XML element

in request body:

```
...
<ns:myIntegerElement>asdf</ns:myIntegerElement>
...
```

my exception resolver is invoked, this resolver is just an implementation of the exception resolver, so it doesn't have exception mappings, just a few System.out's in the abstract method

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver" class="com.mycompany.ws.MyExceptionResolver">
```

however, if I send a request that looks more like this:

```
...
    <ns:myIntegSOMETHINGGOTTOTALLYMESSUP!!!ent>asdf</ns:myIntegerElement>
...
```

my resolver isn't executed at all

I setup log4j to have a root debug level and see this output:

> 2010-08-09 10:30:01,900
>   [Thread:http-8080-2] DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter]
>   - Accepting incoming [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpServletConnection@c46dcf]
>   to
>   [http://localhost:8080/myws/MyWebServices/]
>   ERROR:  'The element type
>   "ns:MESSEDUPELEMENT" must be terminated by
>   the matching end-tag
>   "".' 2010-08-09
>   10:30:01,920 [Thread:http-8080-2]
>   DEBUG
>   [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet]
>   - Could not complete request org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageException:
>   Could not access envelope: Unable to
>   create envelope from given source: ;
>   nested exception is
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl:
>   Unable to create envelope from given
>   source: 
>           at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.support.SaajUtils.getSaajVersion(SaajUtils.java:162)
>           at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getImplementation(SaajSoapMessage.java:251)
>           at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.(SaajSoapMessage.java:84)
>           at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.(SaajSoapMessage.java:70)
>           at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:168)
>           at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:90)
>           at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:86)
>           at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:57)
>           at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:230)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   Caused by:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl:
>   Unable to create envelope from given
>   source: 
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:114)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:70)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:122)
>           at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.support.SaajUtils.getSaajVersion(SaajUtils.java:159)
>           ... 24 more Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The
>   element type "smm:smm-aid" must be
>   terminated by the matching end-tag
>   "".
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:719)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.transform(EfficientStreamingTransformer.java:393)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:102)
>           ... 27 more Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The
>   element type "smm:smm-aid" must be
>   terminated by the matching end-tag
>   "".
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1231)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
>           at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLFilterImpl.parse(XMLFilterImpl.java:333)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:636)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:707)
>           ... 30 more

It appears that spring is missing a possible exception here, and not wrapping it, but such a basic error condition not being caught seems unlikely to me.  Can anyone help me to find the root of this issue?

I'll include web.xml and servlet.xml too:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

servlet context:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycomp.proj.ws" />
    <bean id="smmService" class="com.mycomp.proj.ws.SMMRequestHandlingServiceStubImpl"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.MarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
        <constructor-arg ref="marshaller"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">
        <property name="mappingLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:mapping.xml</value>
                <value>classpath:hoursOfOperationMapping.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="smmws" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
        <property name="schema" ref="schema" />
        <property name="portTypeName" value="SMM" />
        <property name="locationUri" value="/SMMWebServices/"/>
        <property name="targetNamespace" value="http://mycomp.proj.com" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionResolver" class="com.wdp.smm.ws.MyExceptionResolver"/>

    <bean id="schema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
        <property name="xsd" value="/WEB-INF/ws.xsd" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've looked more closely at your question and I think that I know what's happening. You exception handler is not called because it is in the higher level in the soap processing. You see, WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter tries to decode the incoming string to an XML before sending it to the marshaller to be processed. Since the XML is invalid the call fails. And since WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter does not support an exception handler, it just rethrows the exception "SaajSoapMessageException".

Now what you can do is create a new class that extends WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter, but that also wraps handleConnection() in a try/catch that uses your exception handler when a exception is throw.

---

By the way, when debugging this kind of problem my approach is to output both method name and line number in log4j. As well as downloading the Spring sources.

Comment: I could subclass, but how would I tell spring to use that implementation?  I don't see any place where that is configurable

Comment: I want to add you're completely correct, however I don't have any solution to actually fixing this problem, I'm not sure how to leverage my implementation of the WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter in my web service project, the way I understand it only certain beans are automatically picked up within the servlet-context.xml.  At some point this week I will try just definining this sub-classed bean in the context file and see if it is used automagically, if you think you know how to override let me know, and the bounty is yours

Comment: I've added now (three years later) an example implementation in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19024207/365237), proving that this answer is correct.

Answer (score 7):

The MessageDispatcherServlet creates its own two instances of EnpointExceptionResolver by default, namely
SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver@1
and
SimpleSoapExceptionResolver@2

And when it resolves an exception the SimpleSoapExceptionResolver@2 will stop any other registered EnpointExceptionResolver to handle an exception.

It took me embarrassingly long to figure out, but the answer is quite simple,
in your servlet context you have to do this:

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver" class="com.wdp.smm.ws.MyExceptionResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think what @thierry-dimitri-roy explained is correct, however I had a lot of issues actually implementing it. For example, just wrapping the handleconnection method isn't enough due to noendpointfoundexception not being thrown. As this is more general issue of handling exceptions nicely, I'm putting my code here to ease the pain for future generations. This is tested with spring-ws 2.1.3 and JBoss AS7.

My message handler converts all problems to soap faults with response code 200.

```
package fi.eis.applications.spring.soap.server.transport.http;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ws.FaultAwareWebServiceMessage;
import org.springframework.ws.InvalidXmlException;
import org.springframework.ws.NoEndpointFoundException;
import org.springframework.ws.WebServiceMessage;
import org.springframework.ws.WebServiceMessageFactory;
import org.springframework.ws.context.DefaultMessageContext;
import org.springframework.ws.context.MessageContext;
import org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.EndpointAwareWebServiceConnection;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.FaultAwareWebServiceConnection;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.WebServiceConnection;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.WebServiceMessageReceiver;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.context.DefaultTransportContext;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.context.TransportContext;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.context.TransportContextHolder;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpServletConnection;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpTransportConstants;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.support.TransportUtils;

/**
 * Adapter to map XML parsing and other low-level errors to SOAP faults instead of
 * server standard error pages. Also, this class will always use return code HTTP_OK
 * (status 200) to requests, even if there are errors.
 *  
 */
public class MyWebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter
    extends WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter
    implements HandlerAdapter, Ordered, InitializingBean, ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext context;
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        this.context = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        DefaultStrategiesHelper defaultStrategiesHelper = new DefaultStrategiesHelper(MessageDispatcherServlet.class);
        WebServiceMessageFactory factory = defaultStrategiesHelper
                .getDefaultStrategy(WebServiceMessageFactory.class, context);
        setMessageFactory(factory);
    }

    public ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                               HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                               Object handler) throws Exception {
        if (HttpTransportConstants.METHOD_POST.equals(httpServletRequest.getMethod())) {
            WebServiceConnection connection = new MyWebServiceConnection(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
            try {
                overriddenHandleConnection(connection, (WebServiceMessageReceiver) handler);
            } catch (InvalidXmlException ex) {
                handleInvalidXmlException(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, handler, ex);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                handleGeneralException(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, handler, ex);
            }
        }
        else {
            handleNonPostMethod(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, handler);
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * Overridden version of handleConnection from WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport to be able to handle
     * missing endpoint ourselves. That method is final, so we need to use another method here.
     * 
     * This has been reported as https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWS-850
     * 
     * @param connection
     * @param receiver
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected void overriddenHandleConnection(WebServiceConnection connection, WebServiceMessageReceiver receiver)
            throws Exception {
        logUri(connection);
        TransportContext previousTransportContext = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
        TransportContextHolder.setTransportContext(new DefaultTransportContext(connection));

        try {
            WebServiceMessage request = connection.receive(getMessageFactory());
            MessageContext messageContext = new DefaultMessageContext(request, getMessageFactory());
            receiver.receive(messageContext);
            if (messageContext.hasResponse()) {
                WebServiceMessage response = messageContext.getResponse();
                if (response instanceof FaultAwareWebServiceMessage &&
                        connection instanceof FaultAwareWebServiceConnection) {
                    FaultAwareWebServiceMessage faultResponse = (FaultAwareWebServiceMessage) response;
                    FaultAwareWebServiceConnection faultConnection = (FaultAwareWebServiceConnection) connection;
                    faultConnection.setFault(faultResponse.hasFault());
                }
                connection.send(messageContext.getResponse());
            }
        }
        catch (NoEndpointFoundException ex) {
            if (connection instanceof EndpointAwareWebServiceConnection) {
                ((EndpointAwareWebServiceConnection) connection).endpointNotFound();
            }
            throw ex;
        }
        finally {
            TransportUtils.closeConnection(connection);
            TransportContextHolder.setTransportContext(previousTransportContext);
        }
    }

    private void logUri(WebServiceConnection connection) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            try {
                logger.debug("Accepting incoming [" + connection + "] at [" + connection.getUri() + "]");
            }
            catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
    }



    private void handleGeneralException(
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            Exception ex) throws IOException {
        writeErrorResponseWithMessage(response, ex.getClass().getName() + ": " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    /**
     * By default, sets SC_BAD_REQUEST as response in Spring, so overwritten to
     * provide HTTP_OK and reasonable SOAP fault response.
     */
    protected void handleInvalidXmlException(
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, InvalidXmlException ex)
            throws IOException {
        writeErrorResponseWithMessage(response, ex.getClass().getName() + ": " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    /**
     * By default, sets SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED as response in Spring, so overwritten to
     * provide HTTP_OK and reasonable SOAP fault response.
     */
    protected void handleNonPostMethod(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                       HttpServletResponse response,
                                       Object handler) throws Exception {
        writeErrorResponseWithMessage(response, "HTTP Method not allowed");
    }

    private void writeErrorResponseWithMessage(HttpServletResponse response, String message)
            throws IOException {
        String errorXml = String.format(
                 "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                +"    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>"
                +"    <SOAP-ENV:Body>"
                +"        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>"
                +"            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>"
                +"            <faultstring xml:lang=\"en\">%s</faultstring>"
                +"        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>"
                +"    </SOAP-ENV:Body>"
                +"</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>",
                StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(message)
                );

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        response.getWriter().write(errorXml);
        response.getWriter().flush();
    }
    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 1;
    }

    /**
     * This class is needed as org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpServletConnection will throw an
     * exception if it is used outside Spring framework files. However, extending it and using the same
     * implementation seems to be fine.
     *
     */
    static class MyWebServiceConnection extends HttpServletConnection {
        protected MyWebServiceConnection(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
            super(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
        }
    }    
}
```

This needs to be also configured correctly. This is the thing that is needed on spring context:

```
<!-- 'messageReceiverHandlerAdapter' is a magic name spring-ws
     org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet
     will bind to -->
<bean id="messageReceiverHandlerAdapter"
    class="fi.eis.applications.spring.soap.server.transport.http.MyWebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter">
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution I could come up with is to override the doService method in the MessageDispatcherServlet and capture the exception, then render a custom response. This might not be the best solution for you, but it works for me, hope this helps!

```
public class CustomMessageDispatcherServlet extends MessageDispatcherServlet {

protected void doService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    try {
        super.doService(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String error = e.getMessage();
        String errorXml = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
                                "<SOAP-ENV:Header/>" +
                                    "<SOAP-ENV:Body>" +
                                        "<SOAP-ENV:Fault>" +
                                            "<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>" +
                                            "<faultstring xml:lang=\"en\"></faultstring>" + error +
                                        "</SOAP-ENV:Fault>" +
                                    "</SOAP-ENV:Body>" +
                                "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        response.getWriter().write(errorXml);
        response.getWriter().flush();
    }
}
```

}

You might want to catch only the exceptions you want to handle.

Replace org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet with your CustomMessageDispatcherServlet in the web.xml file.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>web-services</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>CustomMessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Comment: didn't work for me as by default, org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet will catch the exception by itself and just sets the response code. Due to that, exceptions are never to custom dispatcher servlet.

Answer (score 1):

I remember running into this kind of problem when working with spring-security. I also had issues with my exception resolver not being invoked under some condititions.

The problem then was that there is a filter chain that handles each request. The code that invokes the exception resolvers is a filter in this chain, but it is close to the end of the chain. Hence, if an exception ocurred somewhere within the filters before the exception resolver invoking filter, my resolver would never be invoked.

I am guessing you suffer from something similar here, where envelope parse errors happen before the exception resolver invoking filter. If that is the case, you will have to resort to some other way of handling those exceptions, for example a vanilla servlet filter.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Spring WS version you can use custom webservice message listener

```
public class CustomWebServiceMessageListener extends WebServiceMessageListener {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomWebServiceMessageListener.class);

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message, Session session) throws JMSException {
    try {
        this.handleMessage(message, session);
    } catch (JmsTransportException jmsTransportException) {
        LOG.error(jmsTransportException.getMessage(), jmsTransportException);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JMSException jmsException = new JMSException(e.getMessage());
        jmsException.setLinkedException(e);
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }
}
```

And inject it like this:

```
  <bean id="messageListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="#{properties.concurrentListeners}"/>

    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="queue"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener"/>
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>

</bean>

<bean id="messageListener" class="com.yourproject.transport.CustomWebServiceMessageListener">
    <property name="messageFactory" ref="saajMessageFactory"/>
    <property name="messageReceiver" ref="messageDispatcher"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the doService no longer throws an error for invalid XML and simply sets status to 400, I had to explore further on Chen's answer and implemented the following.

```
public class CustomWebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter extends WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void handleInvalidXmlException(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                           HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                           Object handler,
                                           InvalidXmlException ex) throws IOException {
    String error = ex.getMessage();
    String errorXml = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
        "<SOAP-ENV:Header/>" +
        "<SOAP-ENV:Body>" +
        "<SOAP-ENV:Fault>" +
        "<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>" +
        "<faultstring xml:lang=\"en\"></faultstring>" + error +
        "</SOAP-ENV:Fault>" +
        "</SOAP-ENV:Body>" +
        "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
    httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    httpServletResponse.setContentType("text/xml");
    httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(errorXml);
    httpServletResponse.getWriter().flush();
  }
}
```

On the bean configuration updated `messageDispatcherServlet` as below by setting `messageReceiverHandlerAdapterBeanName` to use the custom `WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter`.

```
  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setMessageReceiverHandlerAdapterBeanName("customMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter");
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
  }

  @Bean
  public CustomWebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter customMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter() {
    CustomWebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter customWebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter =
        new CustomWebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter();
    customWebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.setMessageFactory(new DomPoxMessageFactory());
    return customWebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to "wire" (or "inject") the exception handler in your spring beans. I'm not sure which of your Spring bean actually needs the exception handler.

Personally, I use `default-autowire="byName"`, which cause my exceptionHandler to be wired in my Controller class automatically. Your approach actually use manual wiring. So you need to find out which bean should actually use the exception handler. Have you tried (just on top of my head):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.MarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
    <constructor-arg ref="marshaller"/>
    <property name="exceptionHandler" ref="exceptionHandler" />
</bean>
```

Or you could just add the autowired mechanism of Spring and let it wire the beans automatically. :)

Comment: the exception resolver I defined is automatically used during the lifecycle of the SOAP call, however the exception that I gave the trace of is for some reason not handled by it.  Either it's because the resolver doesn't handle exceptions yet in the life-cycle, or this exception is somehow slipping through uncaught.

Comment: I say this because the MarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter doesn't have a property "exceptionHandler", so you could not inject one in this fashion, unless I'm missing something