# Using Spring 3 @ExceptionHandler with commons FileUpload and SizeLimitExceededException/MaxUploadSizeExceededException

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload, exception, apache-commons-fileupload

I am having trouble with catching and gracefully handling commons fileupload's `FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException` or spring's `MaxUploadSizeExceededException` when uploading large files.

From what I can tell these exceptions are thrown during data binding, before the controller is actually reached, therefore resulting in a 500 and no calling of the exception handler method. Has anyone come across this before, and what is the best way for handling these exceptions properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

thanks to thetoolman for this simple solution. I extended it a bit. I wanted to leave the file handling untouched and transport the Exception to the Controller.

```
package myCompany; 

public class DropOversizeFilesMultipartResolver extends CommonsMultipartResolver {

    /**
     * Parse the given servlet request, resolving its multipart elements.
     * 
     * Thanks Alexander Semenov @ http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?62586
     * 
     * @param request
     *            the request to parse
     * @return the parsing result
     */
    @Override
    protected MultipartParsingResult parseRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {

        String encoding = determineEncoding(request);
        FileUpload fileUpload = prepareFileUpload(encoding);

        List fileItems;

        try {
            fileItems = ((ServletFileUpload) fileUpload).parseRequest(request);
        } catch (FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException ex) {
            request.setAttribute(EXCEPTION_KEY, ex);
            fileItems = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
            throw new MultipartException("Could not parse multipart servlet request", ex);
        }

        return parseFileItems(fileItems, encoding);
    }
}
```

and in the controller

```
  @InitBinder("fileForm")
  protected void initBinderDesignForm(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new FileFormValidator());
  }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/my/mapping", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView acceptFile(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, FormData formData,
      BindingResult result) {

    Object exception = request.getAttribute(DropOversizeFilesMultipartResolver.EXCEPTION_KEY);
    if (exception != null && FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException.class.equals(exception.getClass())) {
      result.rejectValue("file", "<your.message.key>");
      LOGGER.error(exception);
    }
```

the spring config remains the same. It would be really nice to have the exception transported to the validator, but I haven't figured out how to do this yet.

Comment: Be aware that by setting `fileItems = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;`, all request parameters are discarded. In other words, `request.getParameterMap()` will be `{}`.

Comment: @Markus' comment is specially important to bear in mind if one of the request parameters is a csrf token. Setting `fileItems = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;` discards the CSRF token, causing the CSRF filter to treat this request as invalid.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but I was looking for a solution to this as well and could not find anything. We are providing RESTful services using Spring and we are doing file upload and were not sure how to handle this. I came up with the following and hopefully it will be useful to someone:

All our exceptions are handled with annotations, so we have our error handler resolver set-up like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig{

    @Bean
    public AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionResolver(){

        final AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver resolver = new AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver();
        resolver.setMessageConverters(messageConverters());
        resolver;
    }
}
```

Then a common class that can handle the exception

```
public class MultipartExceptionHandler
{

    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED)
    @ResponseBody
    protected CustomError handleMaxUploadSizeExceededException(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response, final Throwable e)
            throws IOException
    {
        logger.error(e);
        CustomError c = new CustomErrorMaxFileSize("Max file size exceeded", MAX_FILE_SIZE);
        return c;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MultipartException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody
    protected CustomError handleGenericMultipartException(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response, final Throwable e)
            throws IOException
    {
        logger.error(e);
        CustomError c = new CustomErrorGeneric("There was a problem with the upload");
        return c;
    }
}
```

Then we subclass the commons multipart resolver and implement the HandlerExceptionResolver interface

```
@Component(value="multipartResolver") // Spring expects this name
public class MyMultipartResolver extends CommonsMultipartResolver implements HandlerExceptionResolver
{

    // This is the Spring bean that handles exceptions
    // We defined this in the Java configuration file
    @Resource(name = "exceptionResolver")
    private AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionResolver;

    // The multipart exception handler with the @ExceptionHandler annotation
    private final MultipartExceptionHandler multipartExceptionHandler = new MultipartExceptionHandler();

    // Spring will call this when there is an exception thrown from this
    // multipart resolver
    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(
            final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response,
            final Object handlerParam,
            final Exception ex)
    {

        // Notice that we pass this.multipartExceptionHandler 
        // and not the method parameter 'handlerParam' into the 
        // exceptionResolver. We do this because the DispatcherServlet 
        // doDispatch() method calls checkMultipart() before determining
        // the handler for the request. If doing the multipart check fails 
        // with a MultipartException, Spring will never have a reference  
        // to the handler and so 'handlerParam' will be null at this point. 
        return exceptionResolver.resolveException(request, response, this.multipartExceptionHandler, ex);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a quite common problem. I've had similar problems and similar questions have been asked, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441183/spring-web-services-exception-skipping-exceptionresolver/3530620). I have yet to see a nice solution to the problem. You could use a vanilla servlet filter to handle these exceptions, but that will duplicate your error handling since you already have an ExceptionHandler.

Comment: Yes, the question you linked was one of the many I came across in my research where the question is asked but no clean solution found. I was hoping there was a nicer way, but I agree that a filter or even a wrapper for the resolver might be the only way.